# Error when deploying by USB to Hololens 1 after build using Unity

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, hololens, openxr

I am trying to deploy and run Hololens 1 app to the device by USB with Unity.

I follow this tutorial (and many more on YouTube before it):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/tutorials/mr-learning-base-02?tabs=openxr

I even tried to use two difference Hololens 1 devices! (But I only used one cable)

Unity version: 2020.3.13f1

When I plug the Hololens to the PC I am hearing the sound of window when something connected (But can't see the storage of the Hololens after connecting) and the Hololens are being charged.

I on developer mode in the windows and on the Hololens.
I paired the Hololens with the correct pin code from the Visual Studio.

[image]

Output:

```
Creating a new clean layout...
Copying files: Total 75 mb to layout...
Checking whether required frameworks are installed...
Registering the application to run from layout...
RemoteCommandException: AppxManifest.xml(43,6): error 0x80070002: Cannot map the gazeinput well-known device name to a device interface GUID for the Template3D_1.0.0.0_x86__pzq3xp76mxafg package. Check that the device name is correct.

0x80070002
DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. [0x80004005] Failed to register through new deployment pipeline.
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
DEP6953: Failed to launch remote debugger with the following error: 'Command failed: 0x80270254'.
```

I have no idea what to try next. I don't understand the error and where is comes from. I think that it probably windows can't send to the device or get into the storage of the device for some reason.

Thanks!

Comment: Try to rather [create an app package](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps) and upload it directly via the [Device portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/mixed-reality/develop/platform-capabilities-and-apis/using-the-windows-device-portal#sideloading-applications)

Comment: You mention you are on HoloLens 1 - that one does not have gaze tracking hardware. Take out the gaze ref from the manifest?

Comment: @Nzc Do you mean disable in Hand tracking in Player Settings? I did it and it doesn't work

Comment: It says "Cannot map the gazeinput", which is expected on HL1. As long as you are on HL1, Hernando's suggestion below sounds sensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity 2020 does not support targeting HoloLens (1st gen). These headsets remain supported in Unity 2019 LTS with Legacy Built-in XR for the full lifecycle of Unity 2019 LTS through mid-2022. So, it is recommended to go back to a previous version of the Unity(2019LTS) and Legacy XR pipeline. For more detail, please refer to this link: [Choosing a Unity version and XR plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/choosing-unity-version)